# How to find out my PC Product Number and Model

Tags: windows, hp-pavilion

Just recently, i tried to download some drivers from [hp website](http://h20180.www2.hp.com/apps/Nav?h_pagetype=s-002&h_lang=en&h_cc=us&h_product=5046256&h_client=S-A-R163-1&h_page=hpcom&lang=en&cc=us), only to find out that I have to select my product model to be able to download the right driver for my PC. I know I am using HP Pavilion g6 but I never knew it is of different types. I have tried searching on to get my PC product model or number but no threads seem to help. Please, how can I find the information ?

Comment: Did you check the following article? [How Do I Find My Model Number or Product Number?](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00033108&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en)

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, the model and serial number for your model are on a sticker under the battery.

Try taking out the battery and reading what is on the label.

Answer (score 1):

A HP Support dude once told me to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to bring up a dialog that displays Model and Product numbers (among other things).

Please also refer to [this](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=au&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c00033108) page for many different ways to find this information.